# How to organize a MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I have two models.

```
public class Model1
{
    public type Property1 { get; set; }
    public type Property2 { get; set; }
    public type Property3 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public type Property1 { get; set; }
    public type Property2 { get; set; }
    public List<Model1> List { get; set; }
    public type Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

The value of `Property4` depends on properties of elements of `List`. For example maximal value or average value.

Also I have `DetailsModel2Page` that displays all properties of `Model2` on the screen. On this page I can changes properties of elements of `List`. Since `Property4` depends on these properties, its value will be changed. The changes of `Model1.Property1`, `Model1.Property2`, `Model1.Property3` and `Model2.Property4` must update UI.

How can I design models, views and viewmodels in this case?

Comment: Please implement as much of this as you can. For example, "The changes of ... must update UI" is straightforward MVVM / Data Binding, covered in corresponding Maui docs, and countless examples and questions for xamarin forms. Get to a point where you can ask "what should I put in xaml/c# here?", where "here" is a **specific detail** on which you are stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To me, it sounds like you may want to read more about MVVM and maybe go through some examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The changes of Model1.Property1, Model1.Property2, Model1.Property3
> and Model2.Property4 must update UI.

For this problem, you can implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for class `Model1` , and make following changes to each properties inside it. Once changing the value of its properties, the UI will update automatically.

```
public class Model1: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       // public string Property1 { get; set; }

        int  _property1;
        public int Property1
        {
            set {

                SetProperty(ref _property1, value);

                getAverageValue(Property1);
            }

            get { return _property1; }
        }

        private void getAverageValue(int parameter)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------> message is sended   ");
            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Hi");
        }



        // public string Property2 { get; set; }
        string _property2;
        public string Property2
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _property2, value); }

            get { return _property2; }
        }


        // public string Property3 { get; set; }

        string _property3;
        public string Property3
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _property3, value); }

            get { return _property3; }

        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

> The value of Property4 depends on properties of elements of List. For
> example maximal value or average value.

Here, you also need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for class `Model2` and make changes to property `Property4` .

> On this page I can changes properties of elements of List. Since
> Property4 depends on these properties, its value will be changed

Here, you need to notify property `Property4`  once changing  the value of properties of elements of `List`, you can try [`MessagingCenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

I created a demo and achieved this , you can refer to the following code:

```
public class Model2: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public List<Model1> List { get; set; }

        //public string Property4 { get; set; }
        int _property4;
        public int Property4
        {
            set
            {

                SetProperty(ref _property4, value);

            }

            get { return _property4; }
        }

        public Model2() {

            List = new List<Model1>();

            List.Add(new Model1 { Property1 = 1 ,Property2="test"}) ;
            List.Add(new Model1 { Property1 = 2, Property2 = "test" });
            List.Add(new Model1 { Property1 = 3, Property2 = "test" });
            List.Add(new Model1 { Property1 = 4, Property2 = "test" });
            List.Add(new Model1 { Property1 = 5, Property2 = "test" });
            List.Add(new Model1 { Property1 = 6 , Property2 = "test" });

            // get the average value for Property4 
            calculateAverage();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Hi", (sender) =>
            {
                // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------> message is received   ");
                calculateAverage();

            });
        }

        public void calculateAverage() {
            int sum = 0;

            foreach (Model1 model in List)
            {
                sum += model.Property1;
            }

            Property4 = sum / List.Count;
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

DetailsModel2Page.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp102.DetailsModel2Page"
             Title="DetailsModel2Page">
    <VerticalStackLayout>


        <ListView  x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="60" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Entry Text = "{Binding Property1,Mode=TwoWay}"      FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                                <Label Text = "{Binding Property2}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="50, 35, 200, 25"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label
            Text="{Binding Property4}"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

DetailsModel2Page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class DetailsModel2Page : ContentPage
{
      public DetailsModel2Page()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new Model2();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I add a command to `Model2` and `Property1` will be changing by this command. Also  `Property4` can be recalculating in the command. Then I don't need MessagingCenter. Will it be correct?

Comment: If you change  property `Property1` and property  `Property4 ` of model `Model2 `, you do not need `MessagingCenter`. But if you change property `Property1` of model `Model1`, you need to take a method such as `MessagingCenter` to notify `Model2`.